# Passing GET parameters in mod_rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite

I've build a set of mod_rewrite rules but I have a problem.

For example, I have the following url rewritten: `http://dummydomain.com/category/something.html` that points to `http://dummydomain.com/index.php?page=category&thing=something`. If I put GET params in the first url I don't get them in my php program. How can I tweak this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the `[QSA]` ("[query string append](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)") flag at the end of your rules.